# How to wait for an event from Event Emitter in typescript using async/await in nodejs typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, events, async-await

I have a typescript application running on NodeJS where I use Event Emitter class to emit an event when a value of a variable is changed.

I want to wait for the event to happen to proceed further and hence I need to induce a wait in my typescript code.

This is what I am doing,

```
if (StreamManagement.instance.activeStreams.get(streamObj.streamContext).streamState === 'Paused') {
     await StreamManagement.instance.waitForStreamActive(streamObj);
}
```

This is my waitForStreamActive method,

```
public async waitForStreamActive(stream: Stream) {
    const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

    return new Promise(( resolve ) => {
      eventEmitter.on('resume', resolve );
    });

}
```

And I trigger the emit event like this,

```
public async updateStream(streamContext: string, state: boolean): Promise<string> {
    const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
    if (state === Resume) {
      const streamState = StreamManagement.instance.activeStreams.get(streamContext).streamState = 'Active';
      eventEmitter.emit('resume');
      return streamState;
    }
 }
```

All these three code snippets are in different classes and in different files.

This snippet of code doesn't seem to work as I expected.

I want to achieve a wait in javascript until the promise is resolved. That is until the state is changed to resume.

Can someone please point me where I am going wrong?

Comment: You cannot emit from one `eventEmitter` instance and listen on another instance. Each instance is independent.

Comment: Oh. I didnt know that. Thanks. I am relatively new to typescript. Is it the only mistake here? Rest all are okay?

Comment: Do you want a value return from that promise inside `waitForStreamActive` or not? Currently you have `undefined` returned, look suspicious. Other parts look good.

Comment: I dont want to return any value from the promise? I just want the promise to get resolved when the event is emitted and wait till then.

Comment: async/await + events seem to be an odd combination

Comment: I could only think of this solution for my use case. What else do u suggest?

Comment: @JaromandaX I think it's fine, this looks like an ad hoc reactive paradigm to me. Key feature here is flow control. Await promise establishe the flow, and emitter do the control.

Comment: I guess a "once" event works with promises

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please point me where I am going wrong?

You have two *different* `EventEmitter`s. Events triggered on one `EventEmitter` *do not* fire on others.

## More Code Review

Firing and listening on the *same* `EventEmitter` will work. That said, `Promise` is not the correct abstraction for things that return *multiple* times. A `Promise` can only be resolved *once*, whereas Events can fire multiple times. Suggest using `EventEmitter` as is, or alternatively use some other stream abstraction e.g. `Observable`

Answer (score 1):

EventEmmitter(Obserbable pattern) and Promise(Chain of responsibility pattern), they have different obligations. I see that you want use them both. In your case it is not impossible because EventEmitter is not design for to chain observer processors. Use simple promises and builders only. There is a very good library RxJS it provides a lot of functionality. It can do what you ask: to build event driven architecture with sync/async chained cases.